# How to separate numerical values from identifiers

Tags: text-processing, command-line, grep, numeric-data

I'm currently writing a shell script that separate values from their identifiers (retrieved from grep).

For example, if I grep a certain file I will retrieve the following information:

```
value1 = 1
value2 = 74
value3 = 27
```

I'm wondering what UNIX command I can use to take in the information and convert it to this format:

```
1 74 27
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) like this :

```
grep "pattern" file.txt | awk '{printf "%s ", $3}'
```

Depending of what you do with `grep`, but you should consider using `awk` for *greping* itself :

```
awk '/pattern/{printf "%s ", $3}' file.txt
```

Another way by taking advantage of [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) *word-spliting* :

```
echo $(awk '/pattern/{print $3}' file.txt)
```

**Edit** : I have a more funny way to *join* values :

```
awk '/pattern/{print $3}' file.txt | paste -sd " " -
```

Comment: Thanks, is there some way I can get it to print without the newlines though?

Comment: See my edited post

Comment: @sj755 If this answer solved your problem, please remember to mark it as accepted and upvote it instead of posting a thank you comment. That is the way thanks are expressed on SE sites.

Comment: @terdon Well aware, I'm waiting to be allowed to check off the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Strip everything up to the first `=` and subsequent whitespace, convert newlines into spaces, and print a final newline:

```
… | sed 's/^[^=]*= *//' | tr '\n' ' '; echo
```

Answer (score 1):

How about simply

```
cut -d= -f2 /tmp/file | xargs printf "%s "
```

This works because:

1. The shell builtin "printf" will will "repeat itself" if it gets more
   arguments than the parameters specified in the output string
2. xargs will turn the lines from the input into words on the command
   line passed to printf
3. cut will use the = as a separator and deliver only what follows it
4. Of course the printf string will display the output and since no
   explicit new line is added, append each to the end of the previous
   one.